# Programmatically adding SharePoint Library Teams Tab to Microsoft Teams Channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to add a `SharePoint Library` tab to a Microsoft Team Channel programmatically through the Microsoft Graph.
Here is the payload I'm sending through the Graph Explorer `POST`

```
{
    "teamsAppId": "com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.files.sharepoint",
    "name": "Documents3",
    "sortOrderIndex": "10300",
    "configuration": {
        "siteUrl": "https://baywet.sharepoint.com/sites/customerhub",
        "libraryServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/customerhub/Shared Documents",
        "selectedDocumentLibraryTitle": "Documents",
        "selectedSiteTitle": "customerhub",
        "dateAdded": "2018-10-05T16:56:59.169Z"
    }
}
```

I get a 201 status response, my tab is added to the channel. **However whenever somebody tries to upload a file from the Teams UI, they get the following error message `The File {filename} is missing`**. If they click on `Open in SharePoint` and then upload the file, it works.
[image: teams error message]
If I compare with a tab created through the UI (which works properly) here is the description I get.

```
{
    "id": "a68e34db-9d43-4821-953b-2dec938ce785",
    "name": "Document%20Library",
    "teamsAppId": "com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.files.sharepoint",
    "sortOrderIndex": "10200",
    "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3ab2e05a0aae42487485b13e088d5d2f0f%40thread.skype/tab%3a%3aa63916e6-f252-477d-9696-7934980e7e47?label=Document%2520Library&groupId=71ed6a2e-67ca-4930-a3c2-abb25ca29fbf&tenantId=bd4c6c31-c49c-4ab6-a0aa-742e07c20232",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": null,
        "contentUrl": null,
        "removeUrl": null,
        "websiteUrl": null,
        "siteUrl": "https://baywet.sharepoint.com/sites/customerhub",
        "libraryServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/customerhub/Shared Documents",
        "libraryId": "706FAD5678484E7B93B0855E52A0BCD9",
        "selectedDocumentLibraryTitle": "Documents",
        "selectedSiteImageUrl": "https://baywet.sharepoint.com/sites/customerhub/_api/GroupService/GetGroupImage?id='f9d430ca-4de3-42f1-9474-1427bfdb16b0'&hash=636743460492415245",
        "selectedSiteTitle": "customerhub",
        "dateAdded": "2018-10-05T16:56:59.169Z"
    }
}
```

**The only difference being the `libraryId` configuration value. (you're not supposed to send in the webUrl and id).**
This library id doesn't match the library id in SharePoint, or the drive item id in the Graph so my question is: **what value am I supposed to set for the libraryId**? **Is there anything else I am missing?**

Comment: I wanted to let you know that we are looking into this and will let you know once we've figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution a while after, sorry for not posting here earlier.

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{groupId}/channels/{channelId}/tabs`

```
{
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.files.sharepoint",
    "name": "test",
    "sortOrderIndex": "10400",
    "configuration": {
        "contentUrl": "https://baywet.sharepoint.com/sites/NYC/test"
    }
}
```

Where contentUrl is the URL of the document library

Answer (score 0):

The following code Creates the team for a known Group ID (365 that When created, created a team site) and adds 3 tabs on the existing channel.

```
          IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                 .Create(GraphClientId)
                                 .WithTenantId(GraphTenantId)
                                 .WithClientSecret(GraphClientSecret)
                                 .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var team = new Team
            {
                MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings
                {
                    AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true
                },
                MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings
                {
                    AllowUserEditMessages = true,
                    AllowUserDeleteMessages = true
                },
                FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings
                {
                    AllowGiphy = true,
                    GiphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.Moderate
                }
            };

            Team addedTeam = await graphClient.Groups[GroupID].Team
                .Request()
                .PutAsync(team);

            ECGTeam ecgTeam = new ECGTeam {ProjectNumber= ProjectNumber ,GroupID = GroupID, TeamID = addedTeam.Id };

            string channelID = string.Empty;
            var channels = await graphClient.Teams[addedTeam.Id].Channels.Request().GetAsync();
            channelID = channels[0].Id;
            ecgTeam.ChannelID = channelID;

            TeamsTab newTab = addTab(targetWebUrl, "WorkingPapers", "Working Papers");
            var addedTab = await graphClient.Teams[addedTeam.Id].Channels[channelID].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(newTab);
            ecgTeam.TabWorkingPapersID = addedTab.Id;
            //DPC documents
            newTab = addTab(targetWebUrl, "DPCdocuments", "DPC documents");
            addedTab = await graphClient.Teams[addedTeam.Id].Channels[channelID].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(newTab);
            ecgTeam.TabDPCdocumentsID=addedTab.Id;
            //ContractDocuments //
            newTab = addTab(targetWebUrl, "ContractDocuments", "Contract Documents");
            addedTab = await graphClient.Teams[addedTeam.Id].Channels[channelID].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(newTab);
            ecgTeam.TabContractDocumentsID = addedTab.Id;
            //log.LogInformation(addedTab.Id);
```

Now, If you can help me create a Library for the said site that uses a custom content type, I will buy you coffee :-)
The wealth of good documentation for MS Graph in .NET Core makes me want to cry :-(